# Pass local variable to directive as input

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular, syntactic-sugar

I want to pass `ElementRef` backToTopTarget to directive `.back-to-top`. However I cannot get it with `ngOnChanges`

```
<section #backToTopTarget>
    <section class="back-to-top" [target]="backToTopTarget">
        Back to top <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </section>
</section>
```

---

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Directive, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {BaseComponent} from "../../BaseComponent/BaseComponent";

@Directive({
    selector: '.back-to-top',
})
export class BackToTop implements OnChanges {
    private $el;
    @Input('target') private target;
    private $target;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        this.$el = $(this.el.nativeElement);
    }

    ngOnChanges({target}) {
        // target.currentValue === undefined
    }
}
```

So I cannot or anything I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[check plunker it works](http://plnkr.co/edit/1S8YGkPidc0EbeMxDcDb?p=preview)**

```
ngOnChanges(...args:any[])
{
    console.log(args[0].target); // according to my plunker code
}
```

Comment: No there is only one argument, JSON is as follow: `{"target":{"previousValue":{}}}`

Comment: Please check and implement. I'm sure you will have your `target` value within `args`

Comment: Do you have any default value for `backToTopTarget`? It must work whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `$(this.el.nativeElement)` is supposed to do.

This works fine for me:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '.back-to-top',
})
export class BackToTop implements OnChanges {
    private $el;
    @Input() private target;
    private $target;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        this.$el = this.el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.debug(this.target);
        // outputs `<section></section>`
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [BackToTop],
  template:`
<section #backToTopTarget>
    <section class="back-to-top" [target]="backToTopTarget">
        Back to top <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </section>
</section>
  `,
})
export class App {
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pgy8se?p=preview)